# Hide columns in JQGrid with conditions

Tags: jquery, sql, stored-procedures, jqgrid

I want add data from database to jqgrid when page load using stored procedure. I have certain column "role" and "business" if the role=3 then only business column should be visible, other cases it should be hidden. So how can I retrieve data like this using a stored procedure?

Comment: Please show some code how you create the grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of stored procedure depend on can be done on the backened only. The code depend on the language (C#/Java/PHP, ...), which you use, from the database API (Entity Framework for example) and many other details. Then you should return the information about "business" column in some way to the client (to jqGrid). Finally you should either use `hidden: true` property in the corresponding column of `colModel` or to call `hideCol` method of jqGrid.